# Column with Default value as Sum of TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, timestamp, date, sum, virtual-columns

I have a table which has 2 columns ( `JobDate` , `RecordTime`)

```
--------------------------------------
JobDate       | RecordTime |   SumCol
--------------------------------------
2019-07-20    | 2019-07-21 |
2019-07-19    | 2019-07-20 |
```

I need `SumCol` to have a default value as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(JobDate) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(RecordTime)`

I've tried creating a virtual column but it gives me this error :

**Expression of generated column 'Test2' contains a disallowed function.**

that's what I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `jobsTemp` 
ADD  `SumCol` TIMESTAMP 
AS (UNIx_timestamp(`JobDate`) + UNIx_timestamp(`RecordTime`));
```

Comment: What is meaning of ((Christmas Day) + (New Year's Day))??

Comment: @RickJames
i know that it has no meaning but iam sorting with the two columns , instead of doing this i want to add sum in the third column and order by it only to optimize the query performance

Comment: Have you thought about the general question: What is the sum of two dates? Let's say we just take the years: Is `2022 + 2022 = 4044`? I think you have a misunderstanding of what should happen when you add dates. See this link for an example [Adding Two Dates in MySQL (db<>fiddle)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cda424aeca3b3f180cc7b6ab71fe691)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to order by two columns, then simply do that.

```
SELECT ...
    ORDER BY JobDate, RecordTime
```

This will sort the output rows by `JobDate`, but in the case of duplicates for `JobDate`, it will use `RecordTime`.

Performance?  Not a problem, especially if can manage to get the right 'composite' index.  But we need to see the actual query to discuss that.

Note that your initial thought of adding the columns could lead to a different sort order.  Consider simple numbers:

```
id  JD  RT  JD+RT
 1  14  15    29
 2  14  13    27
 3   6  11    17
 4   7   5    12

SELECT id FROM .. ORDER BY JD+RT   -- 4, 3, 2, 1
SELECT id FROM .. ORDER BY JD,RT   -- 3, 4, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not allow you to use nondeterministic functions in generated columns. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` a nondeterministic function because it interprets dates in the current session timezone.

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', date_column)` to extract a unix timestamp from a date in a deterministic way.

If that is what you want to do, you can change your code to:

```
ALTER TABLE `jobsTemp` 
ADD  `SumCol` TIMESTAMP 
AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', `JobDate`) + TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', `RecordTime`));
```

Comment: The OP is not after the difference between the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the two columns (which could be done by converting the values to numeric) is not going to achieve sorting by two columns because (using numbers) 5+3 = 8 but so does 3+5 = 8.  Sorting by the new column they would be next to each other, when they should not.

If you have an index on JobDate and RecordTime, then the speed is not an issue.  This is just part of the database's job.

However, if you are bent on having a sum then I would suggest that you convert both to string and concatenate them.  So `JobDate=2019-07-20`   and `RecordTime=2019-07-21`  will give you **"2019-07-202019-07-21"**

For example...

```sql
CONCAT (CAST(JobDate as varchar),CAST(RecordTime as varchar))
```